# Computing selected columns of the null space of a sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a large sparse matrix. Typical size is $299K$ by $300K$. I need to construct the null space of this matrix efficiently. The null space in this case is a $1000$ by $300K$ matrix which is in general dense.

My first question is what is the best way to compute this null space? I tried sparse QR factorization based method but the involved matrices are not so sparse and it is not as efficient as I would want it to be.

It seems that an LU factorization of a $300K$ by $300K$ can be computed quite fast so I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this using LU. I'm using Matlab so a Matlab function would be ideal.

Once I'll have the null space I actually need only several columns from it. I can simply extract these columns but it seems as a waste of time. Is there a way to compute only selected columns of the null space rather than all of it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html? It's the documentation for LU decomposition in matlab.

Comment: Matlab's lu can't directly compute a null space. I was looking for a method to compute null space that is as efficient as lu factorization.

Comment: In general, in the LU decomposition, $L$ is nonsingular, so that the nullspace of $LU$ is the nullspace of $U$; it's straightforward to find a basis  for the nullspace of an upper triangular matrix. If you matrix is peculiar, you may need to permute rows ...but matlab can do this for you as well.